Recursively iterating JSON object
[
  {
    name: "pink", messages: [
      { id: "1", message: { color: "red" } },
      { id: "2", message: { color: "red2" } }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "black", messages: [
      { id: "10", message: { color: "yellow1" } },
      { id: "20", message: { color: "yellow2" } }
    ]
  }
]

I want to recursively traverse and reduce it to the following:
[
  {"name": "pink", "id": "1", "message": {"color": "red"}},
  {"name": "pink", "id": "2", "message": {"color": "red2"}},
  {"name": "black", "id": "10", "message": {"color": "yellow1"}},
  {"name": "black", "id": "20", "message": {"color": "yellow2"}}
]

I tried following the thread from: Reduce JSON object containing JSON objects into an array of the form [Path, Value] but I'm unable to modify it to get the correct output.

Is the number of layers of nesting fixed? Will the messages array contain more arrays?

What output do you get, then? Give a [mre].

What code have you tried?

@Unmitigated messages array will not have more arrays it will have more elements though

You could use a combination of flatMap and spread syntax:


const appleObjects = [{name: "pink", messages: [{id: "1", message: {color: "red"}},{id: "2", message: {color: "red2"}}]}, {name: "black",messages: [{id: "10", message: {color: "yellow1"}},{id: "20", message: {color: "yellow2"}}]}];
const result = appleObjects.flatMap(({messages, ...obj}) =>
    messages.map(msg => ({...obj, ...msg}))
);

console.log(result);



